# knex: select rows that are in certain date range

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

How can I select rows from the table that are in certain date range with knex queries? For example, selecting rows from last seven days.

Knex version: 0.15.0

DB: PostgreSQL

Comment: somecases `whereRaw` is your friend.

Comment: Yeap, seems that I will have to use whereRaw

Comment: this is assuming `createdAt` is `timestamp` type, correct?

Comment: @ZivLevy, correct.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Any way you choose to query them should do, here is one way to do it:

```
knex('table')
  .where('createdAt', '>=', '2009-01-01T00:00:00Z')
  .where('createdAt', '<', '2010-01-01T00:00:00Z')
```

Comment: It works for a specific timestamp. I always want to select the rows of last seven days beginning from the current timestamp. Maybe I can use `moment` to get the current timestamp and compare with that one?

Comment: That would be one way to do it.

Answer (score 29):

You can also use:

```js
const from = '2019-01-01';
const to = '2019-02-02';

knex('myTable')
  .select()
  .whereBetween('createdAt', [from, to]);
```

[knex.js `whereBetween` docs](https://knexjs.org/guide/query-builder.html#wherebetween).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `moment`, it will be pretty easy to achieve what you want.
create an `ISO 8601` format date from the date string you have.

```js
let startDate = '2019-01-01';
startDate = moment(startDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
let endtDate = '2019-10-01';
endDate = moment(endDate).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
```

`toISOString()` method will format the date in `YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]` format, which can be used with `knex` to find the record in time range. However, I prefer the `format()` method over `toISOString()` because `format` method uses the default format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ) without milliseconds and maintains the timezone offset.

Now, you can find the relevant records in the given range of `startDate` and `endDate` as given below,

```
knex('records')
  .where('created_at', '>=', startDate.toString())
  .where('created_at', '<', endDate.toString())
  .then((rows) => {
     /*
      * perform operations on record
      */
  })
  .catch((e) => {
       console.log(e);
  });
```

or alternatively, you can use `whereBetween()` from knex as,

```js
knex('records')
  .whereBetween('created_at', [startDate.toString() , endDate.toString()])
  .then((rows) => {
     /*
      * perform operations on record
      */
  })
  .catch((e) => {
       console.log(e);
  });
```

> Note: The `createdAt` column name is replaced with `created_at` in the most recent versions of `knex`. At the time writing this answer i used `knex@0.19.1`. But still you can use `createdAt` with older versions of knex.

Comment: this is assuming `createdAt` is `timestamp` type, correct?

Comment: @ZivLevy exactly

Answer (score 1):

You can just create two different timestamps using Javascript `Date()` object, and convert them to strings.

```
    const currentDate = new Date()

    // Must convert to strings in case you need to prefix a '0' for single digit months or dates
    const currentYear = "" + currentDate.getUTCFullYear()
    const currentMonth = "" + (currentDate.getUTCMonth() + 1) //month indexed at 0
    const currentDay = "" + currentDate.getUTCDate()
    const currentHour = "" + currentDate.getUTCHours()
    const currentMinute = "" + currentDate.getUTCMinutes()
    const currentSeconds = "" + currentDate.getUTCSeconds()

    //Timestamp format: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ
    const yesterdayTimestamp = `${currentYear}-` +
      // Ternaries are for prefixing a 0 to return values that are single digit
      `${currentMonth.length === 2 ? currentMonth : '0' + currentMonth}-` +
      `${currentDay.length === 2 ? currentDay : '0' + currentDay}T` +
      `${currentHour.length === 2 ? currentHour : '0' + currentHour}:` +
      `${currentMinute.length === 2 ? currentMinute : '0' + currentMinute}:` +
      `${currentSeconds.length === 2 ? currentSeconds : '0' + currentSeconds}Z`

    const lastWeek = new Date()
    lastWeek.setUTCDate(currentDate.getUTCDate() - 1)
    // Then do same string manipulations to create timestamp string for one week ago...
```

Answer (score 1):

In your Repo, just put these where clause:

```
  MODEL.query()
          .where('created_at', '>=', '2009-01-01T00:00:00Z')
          .where('created_at', '<', new Date())
          .orderBy('created_at','desc|asc')
```

Above code is useful to get all records from 2009-01-01 till the ongoing date(You can replace new Date() with your own date till which you want the records).

> Ques : How to get 2009-01-01T00:00:00Z from 04/14/2020(MM/DD/YYYY)?

**Answer :**

```
dateSplit = date.split("/");
            date = `${dateSplit[2]}-${dateSplit[0]}-${dateSplit[1]}`;
            date = date + "T00:00:00.000Z";
```

*Note: Do not forget to send date in MM/DD/YYYY. Also it solves the problem of date or time being shown as incremented or decremented.*